# Adding a Paypal button option to my forum

Tags: php, html, forms, forum

I have a simple question about HTML forms and redirecting.

In the editing section of my forums, I would like to add an option next to the submit button to add a Paypal button.  If a check box is clicked, a form will appear for the user to enter their Paypal info. Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/48Agy/).  I would like to use the same submit button for my forum editor to submit the user's Paypal info, however the form action for my Paypal button form differs from the form action of the editor.

So my question is if there is a way to tie the Paypal form and the editor form to a single `input type="submit"` button.  I could then later call each Paypal field with POST or GET (haven't gotten that far).  Or is there a way to define an action for an individual input field, without a form action? Something like

```
<input type="text" name="email" action="paypal_button.php"/>
```

I'm not saying the synax is correct, it's probably not.  I'm just looking for a method to
call an input field with PHP without having to redirect.  I could then somehow call the Paypal input fields within my theming engine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to tie a different fields to different actions like that...

But you CAN tie both forms to the same button by just having a single button processor!

Why don't you just have a single form processor that can handle the form submission whether it's submitted with the paypal info or not?

just check with an

```
if( isset($_POST['paypal_checkbox']) ) { #process paypal stuff here; }
```

add this to the regular php code that process the rest of the other form.